# when or if: How to choose?

Tags: word-choice, conditional-constructions

I've got a question – when do I have to use **when** and when **if**?

Here're some examples:

> If you'll be good, you'll do it.
>
> When you'll be good, you'll do it.

Which one should I use?

Comment: In English we say *I have a **question*** (not *I have a doubt*).

Comment: More idiomatic in English would be: "If you're good, you'll do it". Native English speakers would be unlikely to use either of your examples.

Comment: **When** means "at the time".  **If** just refers to a possibility.  So the choice really depends on whether you're referring to a specific time when the person is good (which you probably aren't).

Comment: [When used as a conjunction, definition #6](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/when), in some particular instances, **when** and **if** can be interchangeable. See also the usage note.

Comment: I think **if** is conditional, it's like you're assuming a possibility in future.

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer is pretty similar to fishyninja1's, but sometimes different language can be clearer to different people.  This builds on stangdon's comment.

"When" means "at the time".  But the crux of the meaning is not that it is a reference to a date or time, rather "coincident with".  It refers to something that has either already happened or is expected to happen.

"If" refers to a possibility.  Implied in that is that it hasn't happened yet, it refers to a potential future event or condition.

"If" is a "decision rule".  It implies that there is (or should be), an associated definition for recognizing when the condition is satisfied ("How will I recognize it when I see it?").  "When" refers to something that has already happened or "will have already happened"; there is no ambiguity in recognizing it.

So there is an additional nuance highlighted by your example about being "good".  "When" implies that both people already have a shared understanding of what "good" means.  "If" is more open-ended and could imply, "I'll decide what constitutes good".

Answer (score -1):

when holds a similar meaning as a subordinating word. when is different to if as it is expecting an event to happen. for example, in your sentences you are waiting for when you'll e good. if usually connotes to that the event might happen: **if you are good**.

Answer (score -2):

**Neither**

*If you're good, you will do it*, but maybe you aren't and you won't. Still, I have faith so I'm reminding you.

*If you were good, you'd do it*, but you aren't and you won't. Hopefully this will make you feel guilty and cause you to change your ways.

*When you're good, you will do it*, but you aren't now so you can't. Still, I'm sure the time will eventually be right.

In any case, for what you're talking about, the difference is that *if* is for when something might not or will not happen and *when* is for when something must eventually happen, as far as you can tell.